# Does data matrix passed into PCA function need to contain the response vector?

Tags: android, python, scikit-learn, pca

I have a training matrix of data (about 15 features and 500+ rows) and a result/response vector (500+ length) whose values correspond to the rows. Basically it's a matrix of android sensor data that corresponds to a radian measurement (I'm trying to use sensor data to predict direction of movement).

I'm trying to identify which features are less important/not useful by using PCA. I am using the PCA function provided by scikit-learn:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html

But all it seems to ask for is the matrix of data; there's no option to input the response vector for the data (or do I include the response vector in the data matrix?).

From what I understand, PCA picks out the features that exhibit the greatest variance with respect to the response variable. If I don't provide the response vector (of radian measurements), how would it know which feature(s) is/are of greater importance?

Comment: `picks out the features that exhibit the greatest variance with respect to the response variable.` - no, basically PCA selects a orthonormal basis such that the spread along the axes are maximized. You may find this interesting: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.1100.pdf

Answer (score 0):

PCA is an unsupervised estimator, which means it does not take any target/response variable into account. It will find orthonormal bases within the data without reference to any target (this is discussed in the [sklearn docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html)).

It sounds like what you have in mind is [Linear Discriminant Analysis](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/lda_qda.html) and related routines: these are supervised algorithms which find linear combinations of features which best discriminate between response variables.